# How to use Android PropertyValuesHolder with proguard

Tags: android, android-animation, proguard

I'm using PropertyValuesHolder to animate some views in my Android application. The animations run fine on my device until I do a release build where there is no animation whatsoever. (I'm thinking the problem has to do with obfuscation since the property name is referred to as a String name eg "Panel1W")

There is no exception thrown. Just no animation. The closest thing I could find on http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/troubleshooting.html  is NoSuchMethodException where we need to use -keep command in proguard.cfg. I tried the following in my proguard.cfg but without success

```
-keep public class com.mycompany.myapp.HomeActivity { java.lang.Integer getPanel1W(); }
-keep public class com.mycompany.myapp.HomeActivity { void setPanel1W(java.lang.Integer); }
-keep public class com.mycompany.myapp.HomeActivity { java.lang.Integer getPanel2W(); }
-keep public class com.mycompany.myapp.HomeActivity { void setPanel2W(java.lang.Integer); }
-keep public class com.mycompany.myapp.HomeActivity { java.lang.Integer getPanel3W(); }
-keep public class com.mycompany.myapp.HomeActivity { void setPanel3W(java.lang.Integer); }
```

Am I missing anything? Here's the code below. Thanks.

```
PropertyValuesHolder[] arrayOfPropertyValuesHolder = new PropertyValuesHolder[3];
arrayOfPropertyValuesHolder[0] = PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("Panel1W", mPanel1.getWidth(), 0);
arrayOfPropertyValuesHolder[1] = PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("Panel2W", 360, 1280);
arrayOfPropertyValuesHolder[2] = PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("Panel3W", 0, (int)(screenWidth * 0.65));

ObjectAnimator localObjectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(this,
arrayOfPropertyValuesHolder).setDuration(time);
localObjectAnimator.setInterpolator(sCollapseInterpolator);
localObjectAnimator.start();
```

I have the getter and setter methods too.

```
    public int getPanel1W() {
        return ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) mPanel1.getLayoutParams()).width;
    }

    public void setPanel1W(int paramInt) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) mPanel1.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = paramInt;
        mPanel1.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }

    public int getPanel2W() {
        return ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) mPanel2.getLayoutParams()).width;
    }

    public void setPanel2W(int paramInt) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) mPanel2.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = paramInt;
        mPanel2.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }  

    public int getPanel3W() {
        return ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) mPanel3.getLayoutParams()).width;
    }

    public void setPanel3W(int paramInt) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) mPanel3.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = paramInt;
        mPanel3.setLayoutParams(lp);        
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

The trick is the fact that the methods called by the `PropertyValuesHolder` are either `set*` or `get*`, so the `ProGuard` rules to keep such methods are:

```
void set*(***);
*** get*();
```

So, based on that, if your animated target is only one of a few classes, add this per animated target class:

```
-keep class my.package.MyClass {
    void set*(***);
    *** get*();
}
```

If all your targets extend some base class, you can add a single rule to save them all:

```
-keep class * extends my.package.MyBaseClass {
    void set*(***);
    *** get*();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check if String "Panel1W","Panel2W" and "Panel3W" were mixed by proguard.I think you can define these strings in class and -keep in proguard.cfg to protect these strings.

Comment: Thanks, I tried defining the strings in the class and tried to keep the whole class with -keep public class <com.mycompany.myapp.HomeActivity> but even that didn't work so maybe I'm on the wrong track. Thanks for the input